# LogStach-Grok: How to match Apache TimeStamp

Tags: apache, timestamp, logstash, logstash-grok, grok

I have no idea how to match my TimeStamp. Could someone please help me?

Example of my TimeStamps from Apache Log: `"2016-06-13T14:54:39.000+0100"`

```
filter {   if [type] == "apache" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }   }
    date {
      timezone     => "UTC"
      match        => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss Z"]
    }   } }

output {   stdout { codec => rubydebug } }
```

Output:

> {:timestamp=>"2016-06-13T14:56:43.196000+0100", :message=>"Error:
>   Cannot register filter date plugin. The error reported is: \n  Illegal
>   pattern component: T for pattern 'yyyy-mm-dd\THH:mm:ss Z'",
>   :level=>:error}

Apache Log Example:

> { "@version": "1", "@timestamp": "2016-06-14T09:11:23.000+0100",
>   "message": "GET /page1/page2/
>   HTTP/1.1", "via": "192.168.1.1", "client-ip": "192.168.1.23",
>   "remote-logname": "-", "remote-user": "-", "recv-time":
>   "[14/Jun/2016:09:11:23 +0100]", "serve-time-microsec": "85471",
>   "request": "GET /page1/page2/
>   HTTP/1.1", "status": "200", "size": "79648", "referer":
>   "http://www.google.com/", "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US;
>   rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13", "url":
>   "/page1/page2/", "query": "",
>   "method": "GET", "protocol": "HTTP/1.1", "vhost": "www.site.com",
>   "received-size": "998" }

Comment: Can you add an example of line from your log? it will be easier to check.

Comment: There is already a line from my log @ItayD. I am having an issue with matching this date format `2016-06-13T14:54:39.000+0100`

Comment: I don't see any line, and i'm asking it because maybe you can use a better grok matcher than `COMBINEDAPACHELOG` which uses date format `%{MONTHDAY}/%{MONTH}/%{YEAR}:%{TIME} %{INT}`.

Comment: Anyway, the format of your original timestamp is: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`

Comment: Thank you that worked @ItayD (The error message has disappeared)! I have added an example of a full Apache Log. I see that the TimeStamp in my Kibana interface is not changing though. Could I ask you why that would be ?

Comment: try deleting your `.sincedb_*` files + delete your elasticSearch index so you'll have a fresh start

Comment: @ItayD Sorry to bother you again. I can see in the file output that it is working. But the time is not changing in the Kibana interface. Do you know what could be overriding this ?

Comment: Have you tried what I wrote above? (sincedb_ & delete index)

Comment: @ItayD I have deleted the file 'sincedb_', How do I delete the index ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114710/discussion-between-itayd-and-infinite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your full log I can see that its already in Json format, so you don't need to use grok filter on message field using `COMBINEDAPACHELOG` pattern.
Just use the date filter with the following format:

```
date {
     timezone  => "UTC"
     match     => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"]
}
```

This is my full logstash.conf file which worked with your example:

```
input {
    file {
      path => "/var/log/test.log"
      codec => json
      start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
filter {
    date {
          timezone     => "UTC"
          match        => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"]
        }
}
output {
    stdout { 
        codec => rubydebug 
    }
}
```